# Embedding Youtube Video in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube

I am trying to add a you tube clip to my rails app.

I have a profiles helper that says

```
  def embed(youtube_url)
     youtube_id = youtube_url.split("=").last
     content_tag(:iframe, nil, src: "//www.youtube.com/embed/#{youtube_id}")
   end
```

In my view i have

```
  <div class="embed-container"> 
        <%= embed(@profile.youtube_url) %>  
      </div>
```

I get an error with my helper that says:

```
NoMethodError at /profiles/8
undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your error code its clear that the Profile with id 8, doesn't have a youtube url. So when you try to apply split (a method meant for string) on it, it causes an error.

Check if the user has a value for the field youtube_url.

To avoid cases in which the user doesn't have youtube_url i suggest the following change to your view.

```
<div class="embed-container">
  <%= embed(@profile.youtube_url) if @profile.youtube_url %>
</div>
```